# бот не может авторизоваться в Amino

Tags: python, бот

пишу на Python
я пытаюсь написать бота который будет выводить Id сообщества в котором состоит пользователь. Но бот не может получить доступ к аккаунту(логин и пароль точно верные)

```
import amino
client= amino.Client()
client.login(email='email',password='password')
subclients = client.sub_clients()
for name, id in zip(subclients.name, subclients.comId):
   print(name, id)
```

при запуске кода выводит:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Danil_NB\Desktop\Python\bot\botId.py", line 3, in <module>
    client.login(email='email',password='password')
  File "C:\Users\Danil_NB\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\amino\client.py", line 199, in login
    if response.status_code != 200: return exceptions.CheckException(json.loads(response.text))
  File "C:\Users\Danil_NB\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\amino\lib\util\exceptions.py", line 822, in CheckException
    elif api_code == 110: raise ActionNotAllowed(data)
amino.lib.util.exceptions.ActionNotAllowed: {'api:statuscode': 110, 'api:duration': '0.097s', 'api:message': 'Action not allowed.', 'api:timestamp': '2021-04-07T14:03:56Z'}
```

[библиотека](https://github.com/Slimakoi/Amino.py) которую использовал

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поменять параметр DeviceId в файле device.json, который автоматически создаётся в одной папке с кодом. Сам же ID можно получить на официальном сервере Amino.py